# how to stop a .getvalues() in a script exceeding for instance 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet script that has  this line:

```
var data = sheet.getRange("c1").getValue();
```

sometimes during busy hours in europe instead of 1.7  seconds  ( I have logged each line of the script to see the elapsed time)  it needs  240 seconds and then is declarated "failed" automatically,  today it stops automatically after 1220  seconds

I tried to add a line after, but till  the  .getValue() is not finished the next  line is useless

```
var data = sheet.getRange("c1").getValue();  

var elapsedTime= date.now() -startTime;
if (elapsedTime > 60000) {return 'die'};   //return 'die' if longer than 1 minute
if (elapsedTime() === 'die') {return};     //Quit after 1 minute
```

Is there the possibility to kill a `.getValue()` line after for instance 20 seconds?

Comment: Welcome to stack.  Tags help you get the answer you need.  The tags you used in your question really had nothing to do with your question.  Start with the language you are using then add things like the api or libraries.  I have fixed your tags.

Comment: thanks,  I choosed the tags,  thinking that the problem could be there ...

Comment: you are working with a free API you are going to have to deal with others using it was well.    Make sure you have retry setup if it time's out